# Initializing thread field initializer with not parameterless delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading

This sound like a dumb question but I am stuck for a while.

### What is the idea?

- I want to have thread which does some work in the background and I
  want to re-use it since it will do same kind of work each time.
- I know that creating new Thread can bring a lot of overhead to the
  CPU(private local variable stack allocations) each thread consumes 1
  MB of memory so I don't want that.

### What do I have so far.

I have action filter which which before each execution of web api controller method and after does some work. In my case this is writing statistics therefore I don't want to initialize new `Thread` instance. Here is my code:

```
public sealed class AnalyzeActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string Key = "__action_duration__";
    private static Thread _worker = new Thread {IsBackground = true}; -- this doesnt compile because Thread class doesn't have parameterless constructor.

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Starts timer and adds statistics per action in Web Api Controllers.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        var actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        StatisticsProvider.Instance.AddTotalCalls(actionName);

        actionContext.Request.Properties[Key] = stopWatch;
        stopWatch.Start();

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Stops timer after finishing execution of action and adds statistics for this action.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            PopulateStatistics(actionExecutedContext);
        }).Start();
    }

    private static void PopulateStatistics(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var actionName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        if (!actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties.ContainsKey(Key)) { return; }
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception != null)
        {
            StatisticsProvider.Instance.AddToFailedCalls(actionName);
            return;
        }

        var stopwatch = actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[Key] as Stopwatch;

        if (stopwatch != null)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            StatisticsProvider.Instance.AddToTotalTime(actionName, stopwatch.Elapsed);
            StatisticsProvider.Instance.CheckForMinCallTime(actionName, stopwatch.Elapsed);
            StatisticsProvider.Instance.CheckForMaxCallTime(actionName, stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }

        if (actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StatisticsProvider.Instance.AddToFailedCalls(actionName);
        }

        StatisticsProvider.Instance.CalculateAvgTotalTime(actionName);
        StatisticsProvider.Instance.ChangeLastProcessDate(actionName, DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

}
```

### What are my questions?

- How do I write static Thread field initializer invoking method that has parameters? I want to remove the code from `OnActionExecuted` method and just invoke `Start()` method of the field thread.
- Is this worth a try or creating new Thread and letting thread scheduler deal with the overhead, because I also don't want to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Forget threads and use tasks

Comment: Well after all tasks are background threads , right?

Comment: Well, you will never know if there is a thread or not but you do not have to care about. It will run asynchron. Read the excellent blog from Stephen Cleary about async await and tasks https://blog.stephencleary.com

Comment: For background processing on ASP.NET, you should rely on QueueBackgroundWorkItem: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/

Comment: What do you mean creating thread for each filter ? Isn't my filter initialized once at start ? :O

Comment: Did you count, how many times your filter being created? Using threads in ASP.NET could lead to dangerous consequences.